# Why does this query function returns incorrect results?

Tags: google-sheets, search, vlookup

I have a sheet with First Name Variants on one tab and a search table called "Import" on another. I used a Query function
`=if(B4="","",QUERY('First Names'!B:C, "Select C where B matches '.*"&B4&".*' limit 1",0))`
on the Import tab to return column C on the First Names tab by looking for a partial match in column B.

However, if I type in the name *Jon*, it returns **Jo Video** instead of **John Video**. It does this because of the name *Jonnelle* on the row of **Jo video**.

Another thing, if I type in the name *Bran*, it returns **Branch Video** even if the name *Bran* is not in the entire list. I want to return an N/A error instead.

So my question is How to structure the query formula or other formula to do the job correctly?

Here's a link to the sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ymK9fdfl9Me0QU5OhM44K3RRaXnZ6rTSQXKOyAO1cFc/edit?usp=sharing

Here are some screenshots of the sheet:

[First Names sheet Import tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpxv2.png)
[First Names sheet First Names tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nirDg.png)

Thank you in advance for answering! Will definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` means a string with zero or any length, so `Jonelle` matches `.*Jon.*` and `Branch` matches `.*Bran.*`

In case you want to exactly match a name, it should fulfil any of the following criteria

- being the first name `"^"&B2` OR after a different name `".* "&B2`
  AND
- continue with a different name `B2&",.*"` OR being the last name `B2&"$"`

```
=if(B2="","",QUERY('First Names'!B:C, "Select C where B matches '(^|.* )"&B2&"(,.*|$)' limit 1",0))
```

I have applied this formula to that two cells and you can check.